# How to use Spring Batch to connect to server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-retry

I need help from *experienced Spring Batch programmers* for a particular problem I am having.

I am new to Spring Batch. It has detailed documentation for each class or interface, but next to nothing in all of it working together.

**The Scenario**:
I have a database hosted on the cloud, So I have to make REST calls to get some data from it and save related data to it.
  -  Data retrieval will return a JSON response with data I queried.
  -  Data save will return a JSON response on how many rows were added etc.
  -  All responses will have a valid HTTP status code.
  -  A transaction is complete when the save call is successful with an Http code of 200 and data which shows how many records were inserted is received.

The connection may not always be available, In that case the program must keep retrying every 5 minutes until the whole task is complete.

**What I chose not to do**
I could do some dirty Java tricks (which were surprisingly recommended by many in stack overflow)

1. Threads and sleep (Too crude)
2. Spring's @Scheduled (The scheduler keeps running even after job completion)

**What I tried**
So I decided to use Spring Batch since it seemed to be a framework made for this.

1. I have no file tasks, so I used a Tasklet instead of Readers and
   Writers.
2. The Tasklet interface can return only FINISHED status code. No codes
   for FAILURE
3. So, inside the tasklet, I set a custom value in the StepContext and retrieved my custom
   value in a StepExecutionListener and accordingly configured
   ExistStatus of the Step to FAILURE
4. To handle this workaround I had to configure a JobExecutionListener
   to make the Job fail accordingly.

Apart from all these above work-arounds,

1. Spring batch does not have any scheduling. I have to end up using
   another scheduler.
2. Spring Batch's retry within a step is valid only
   for ItemReader,ItemWriter etc and not for tasklets

**The Question**

1. Is Spring Batch right for this situation?
2. Is my design correct? It seems very "hack"-ey.

I need help  with the most efficient way to handle my scenario

Comment: This another scheduler you use, doesn't it keep running even after job completion?

Comment: `I have to make REST calls to get some data from it and save related data to it`

What kind of data your REST call returns? How big is the result? Where are you going to save data?

    `The connection may not always be available, In that case the program must keep retrying every 5 minutes until the whole task is complete.`

Can you define when the task is considered `complete`? This is important to implement your `CompletionPolicy` in Spring Batch

Comment: From your listed requirements, I don't see a need for Spring Batch. Presumably, you could create a @Scheduled method to connect to the cloud REST service, and in this method, implement your own retry logic in the event of connection or business logic failures. I don't quite understand your reluctance to use the scheduler  (The scheduler keeps running even after job completion) - that's what a scheduler is for.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I have updated my question. Size of response data from server is relatively small and is in JSON format. All save operations are Http POST calls to the server. And finally an operation is complete when the final save operation returns a http code 200 (instead of timing out in case of network failure). I would love to hear your approach to this scenario in spring batch

Comment: There is always a way to implement custom modules. I am a student and would like to learn more on standard frameworks that can do thiis. @Scheduled causes scalability issues. Imagine 1million schedulers still running every 5 minutes after their requests were completed long ago.

Comment: When you get the data from your rest call, do you need to iterate over items in it or you just need to do a post request to save it elsewhere?

Comment: Yes. To keep it very simple. 1. I call REST GET endpoint of database. I get some result. 2. Create a new object based on this result 3. Put this object back to the database using a REST POST call.    Note: My main challenge is to restart and continually try this whole atomic operation in case of network failure. Feel free to post your design as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was using spring batch for similar case - as a execution engine to process large files which resulted as lots of REST requests to other systems.

What Spring batch brought for me:

- execution engine/model for large dependent operations. In other words I could maintain my input as one single entry point and have 'huge' transaction on top of other small operations.
- Possibility to see execution results and monitor them.
- Retriability of batch operations. This is one of the best thing in spring batch
- it allows you design your operation in such manner that if something goes wrong in the middle of execution, you can simply restart it and continue from failing point. But you need to invest some effort to maintain this.

More on business cases here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/spring-batch-intro.html#springBatchUsageScenarios

So you need to check carefully those business cases and answer yourself if you really need them.
So far what you have described - I really don't see benefit of spring batch for you.